# Reconding dbl+lbl variables

Tags: categories, numeric, labeling

I need to recorde some variables I imported using haven.
The variables are dbl+lbl labelled.

```
0 = [no]
1 = [yes]
```

I need to recode this variable to

```
1 = [yes]
2=  [no]
```

I used:
`data_MUENSTER$gender[data_MUENSTER$gender == 0 ] <- 2`

In this case of course the value is recoded correctly, but I have no lable for 2; Is there a way to recoded value and label at once?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for your problem? :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this with some version of `set_value_labels` from the `labelled` package.

```
df |>
mutate(x, ~set_value_labels(., c("Yes" = 1, "No" = 2))))
```